# ResolvePackageNotFound: m2w64_c_win-64 while building R package r-ffbase

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, r-package, cran

I'm trying to install an R package in my anaconda environment DS-ML i've created with conda skeleton. The environment has R and python installed in it.
The R package is called r-ffbase, and it is on CRAN repository.

I'm on C:\users\public. After typing:

```
 conda skeleton cran ffbase
```

a skeleton folder named "r-ffbase" has been created successfully.

**I get a conda exception while building the package** -

```
conda.exceptions.ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - m2w64_c_win-64
```

I couldn't find any package in any channel I think. Where can I get this package from?

And why do I need this package for?

This is for a windows 10 server (win64), with Anaconda installed with conda 4.7.12, numpy 1.16.5 and R version 3.6.1 in the DS-ML enviroment.

I've tried typing in the conda prompt:

```
conda build r-ffbase --R=3.6.1 --numpy=1.16.5
```

**I get the following full error message:**

```
(DS-ML) C:\Users\Public>conda build r-ffbase --R=3.6.1 --numpy=1.16.5
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Adding in variants from config.variant
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from config.variant
Attempting to finalize metadata for r-ffbase
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for r-ffbase
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\conda-bld\work
  Test:
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\conda-bld\test_tmp
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test:
source activate  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\conda-bld\_test_env
  Build:
source activate  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\conda-bld\_build_env


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py", line 756, in get_install_actions
    actions = install_actions(prefix, index, specs, force=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 474, in install_actions
    txn = solver.solve_for_transaction(prune=prune, ignore_pinned=not pinned)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
    should_retry_solve)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
    force_remove, should_retry_solve)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 275, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 555, in _add_specs
    explicit_pool = ssc.r._get_package_pool(self.specs_to_add)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 523, in _get_package_pool
    pool = self.get_reduced_index(specs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 544, in get_reduced_index
    explicit_specs, features = self.verify_specs(explicit_specs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 280, in verify_specs
    raise ResolvePackageNotFound(bad_deps)
conda.exceptions.ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - m2w64_c_win-64

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 445, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 436, in execute
    verify=args.verify, variants=args.variants)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 209, in build
    notest=notest, need_source_download=need_source_download, variants=variants)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 2343, in build_tree
    notest=notest,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 1334, in build
    output_metas = expand_outputs([(m, need_source_download, need_reparse_in_env)])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 746, in expand_outputs
    for (output_dict, m) in _m.copy().get_output_metadata_set(permit_unsatisfiable_variants=False):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\metadata.py", line 2047, in get_output_metadata_set
    bypass_env_check=bypass_env_check)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\metadata.py", line 721, in finalize_outputs_pass
    permit_unsatisfiable_variants=permit_unsatisfiable_variants)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 527, in finalize_metadata
    exclude_pattern)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 390, in add_upstream_pins
    permit_unsatisfiable_variants, exclude_pattern)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 378, in _read_upstream_pin_files
    permit_unsatisfiable_variants=permit_unsatisfiable_variants)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 154, in get_env_dependencies
    channel_urls=tuple(m.config.channel_urls))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py", line 758, in get_install_actions
    raise DependencyNeedsBuildingError(exc, subdir=subdir)
conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform win-64: {'m2w64_c_win-64'}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my recipe/meta.yaml:
change

```
requirements:   
      build:
         - {{ compiler("c") }}  # [unix]
         - {{ compiler('m2w64_c') }}  # [win]
         - {{ compiler("fortran") }}  # [unix]
         - {{ compiler('m2w64_fortran') }}  # [win]
```

to:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler("c") }}  # [unix]
    - m2w64-gcc [win]
    - {{ compiler("fortran") }}  # [unix]
    - m2w64-gcc-fortran [win]
```